# why can't i pass a zero for my aws lambda test?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am testing my aws lambda manually on the console.

The pageIndex is blank when 0, but the actual number if > 0?

**index.js**

```
   if (event.queryStringParameters && (event.queryStringParameters.pageIndex)) {
        result = event.queryStringParameters.pageIndex;
```

**test parameter on aws console**

```
{
  "idCustomer": 1,
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "pageIndex": 0,
    "pageSize": 12
  }
}
```

Comment: 0 is treated as false, so your if statement evaluates to `false`

Comment: it is passing the if statement but returning blank still

Comment: Highly recommend that you add logging to your Lambda. Log the event, for example: console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)) and log the execution step by step (e.g. console.log("Got pageIndex, setting result") within the 'if' arm of your code).

Comment: @HunterMcMillen removed check for page index and all is working. How do you check if pageIndex exists? Put in an answer and i'll mark it.

Comment: typically the check is against undefined: `typeof X !== 'undefined'`. You may need to add additional logic to ensure that it is a number

Comment: We used Number.isInteger(value) and seems to work

Comment: @Rod nice, that is probably a better answer than what I suggested. Add it below.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen do you think I need both checks? Is `event.queryStringParameters`  necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Used `Number.isInteger(value)`

```
  if (event.queryStringParameters && Used Number.isInteger(value)) {
        result = event.queryStringParameters.pageIndex;
```